# A woman experiencing the perfect life & family is abruptly awakened to find herself in a chamber

Tags: story-identification, the-twilight-zone

I've been racking my brain on this one! It aired in the 80s as what could have been an Outer Limits or Twilight Zone episode?

The woman had the perfect family when suddenly, the program shuts down and she finds herself in a VR pod or chamber. There are technicians discussing a malfunction in her pod and the camera zooms out to show hundreds of other chambers. I know; it sounds like 50 other movies or tv shows that do exactly the same thing.

Comment: see OP confirmation comment for answer below

Answer (score 42):

Sounds like an episode of the 80s Twilight Zone, ["Dreams for Sale"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreams_for_Sale). Wikipedia has the plot summary:

[image]

> On an idyllic outdoor picnic with her husband and their daughters, a
>   woman becomes confused and disoriented when sounds and sights begin
>   stuttering and events repeat themselves. She awakens and discovers she
>   is in a futuristic dream-making machine alongside hundreds of others
>   in a sterile, industrial environment with no view of the outdoors. A
>   technician explains to her that she was in the Dreamatron "Fully
>   Interactive Dream" machine, running a Country Picnic program.
>
> He fixes the circuit board for her dream bay and tells her to relax
>   and enjoy her last six minutes before returning to work. Apparently,
>   her mind somehow fixed herself in the other life, and not her real
>   life. Still confused, she returns to her dream world and relaxes again
>   in her fantasy, but the machine burns out before technicians can
>   disconnect her, trapping her in the alternate reality forever. All
>   they can do is sadly note, "At least she died happy..."

Comment: OMG!!!! That's it!! Thx so much!!God bless you Hypnosifi!!! I can finally return to my own reality and get some zzzz!

Comment: @EdLoera: If that's it, help out the user who answered the question by picking this as the actual answer.

Comment: @EdLoera You can pick the answer by clicking the **checkmark** icon that's below the vote UP or vote DOWN icons to the left of the top of the answer. That way the question is seen to have an answer, and the answerer gets a little bit more Reputation Points for having posted the best answer. **TOO BAD HE'S RETURNED TO HIS OWN REALITY AND IS ASLEEP AGAIN...**

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeJgK0PTGp4